# set property of model in java make another from database change too

Tags: java

Every time I set the value for `userUpdated` it makes `userInDb` change with it. I went to debug and saw it change immediately. Does anyone know the reason?

```
public synchronized void updateUserForScore(User user) {
        try {
            User userUpdated = user;
            User userInDb = (User) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id").setParameter("id", user.getId()).getSingleResult();
            // if user lose game
            if (userUpdated.getScore() == -1) {
                userUpdated.setLoseNumber(userUpdated.getLoseNumber() + 1); // i set value for userUpdated at here
                if (userInDb.getFlag() == 0) { // and userInDb with LoseNumber change too
                    userUpdated.setFlag(-1);
                    userUpdated.setCurrentLosingStreak(1);
                    userUpdated.setLongestLosingStreak(1);
                }
                if (userInDb.getFlag() == -1) {
                    userUpdated.setFlag(-1);
                    userInDb.setCurrentLosingStreak(userInDb.getCurrentLosingStreak() + 1);
                    if (userInDb.getCurrentLosingStreak() > userInDb.getLongestLosingStreak()) {
                        userUpdated.setLongestLosingStreak(userInDb.getCurrentLosingStreak());
                    }
                }
                if (userInDb.getFlag() == 1) {
                    userUpdated.setFlag(-1);
                    userUpdated.setCurrentLosingStreak(1);
                }
            }

            transaction.begin();
            entityManager.merge(userUpdated);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but why as soon as I change a field in ```userUpdated``` it also changes ```userInDb```

Comment: How do you create the User? Is it retrieved also from em?

Comment: @sigur, yes, it retrieved from same em

Comment: I solved the problem by my way but i still don't understand what happend with it

Comment: Are you using a transaction also? @tedd

Answer (score 1):

#### What's happening

As you change `userUpdated`, the changes are also made to `user` as you are referring `userUpdated` to `user`. For example:-

```
public void update(User user){
    User a = user;
    a.setName("Rahil");

    System.out.println(a.getName());
    System.out.println(user.getName());  // This will print "Rahil" too
}
```

So the change you are making to `userUpdated` will also be made to `user` and since you are using `user.getId()` in `userInDb`, you are actually retrieving the same `user` object which is same as the `userUpdated`

#### Solution

To copy an object, make a constructor that takes another User object. Then set the value of the field from that object. For example-:

```
public void class User {
    int id;
    String name;
    
    public User (User copyFrom){
        id = copyFrom.getId();
        name = copyFrom.getName();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
User userUpdated = new User(user);
```